# Azure - can not deploy -Windows Azure could not find the resource MyCustomLogs in the service package

Tags: logging, azure

The following lines which I included so the custom logging to the default storage account appear in the default WebLogs Table,

```
LocalResource localResource = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("MyCustomLogs");
DirectoryConfiguration dirConfig = new DirectoryConfiguration();
dirConfig.Container = "wad-mycustomlogs-container";
dirConfig.DirectoryQuotaInMB = localResource.MaximumSizeInMegabytes;
dirConfig.Path = localResource.RootPath;
```

produce the error:

> Management URL 'https://management.core.windows.net/'...
>   12:01:03 AM - Connecting...
>   12:01:03 AM - Verifying storage account 'storagetaxiarmy'...
>   12:01:07 AM - Uploading Package...
>   12:01:34 AM - Updating...
>   12:02:23 AM - Windows Azure could not find the resource MyCustomLogs in the service package. You will need to add the resource back or do a full new deployment instead of upgrading an existing deployment.
>   12:02:23 AM - Deployment failed with a fatal error

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it, as redeploying will require a change of VIP address which would be unacceptable. Thank you

Comment: I was fiddling with my local storage names when this happened.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
< LocalStorage name="MyCustomLogs" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" / >
```

In your ServiceDefinition.csdef

Answer (score 0):

In your ServiceDefinition.csdef, do you have *MyCustomLogs* defined as a local resource?